# URL match in a file using shell script

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed

I need to write a unix shell script

Lets say i have a URL maps.google.com
and file1.txt as below:

```
google.com,Id=0
m*.google.com,Id=1
m*r.google.com,Id=2
map*.google.com,Id=3
*p*.google.com,Id=4
*aps.google.com, Id=5
```

Expected Output should be the lines as below which give partial match with text file :

```
m*.google.com,Id=1
map*.google.com,Id=3
*p*.google.com,Id=4
*aps.google.com, Id=5
```

Comment: Please tell us what you have done until now and how we might enlighten your Unix path

Comment: Are the pattern standard filename globbing patterns? Would e.g. `m*.google.com` match `muppets.at.work.google.com`?